# C++ initialising very large constant array, best practice

Tags: c++

My program uses 4 large constant arrays -- 64×256 64-bit integers. Presently I have used some auxiliary code to precompute the values and send them to a file to copy and paste them to the program files. This works, but feels pretty rubbish. I'm pretty certain there must be a far slicker way to precalculate them. They really must be constant!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: including a precomputed table is just another way of metaprogramming - and remember to simply `#include` the generated code (no need for manual copypasta)

Answer (score 5):

Generate the file in a format that you are able to use via an include directive. Then use an `#include` directive to use file directly.

```
your_64bit_type array[] = {
     #include "precomputed.inc"
};
```

This is quite normal when using precomputed table. Also have a look at [XMACROS](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) for another way of using include file tables.

Comment: Thanks: I shall do it that way. Pretty sure I could work out how to get it to run during the build process from the makefile or using some shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way of doing it would be to write a program that outputs the arrays into a header/source file. If the file exists already, dont create it.

Then, you simply ensure that this program is run during the build process. Your IDE should provide an option to run this. If not, I'm sure you can add it to a makefile - dunno, haven't touched them by hand in over 20 years.

I've used a similar process in the past to ensure that each and every copy of the program contained a unique key.